# Why won't setting the time, then re-setting it work out in my favor?

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to program a game called "FIGHT!.bat". I have included the option to save whenever you need to ('cause it's a game), but when I save, the time and date don't update, plus the time appears like for example: "2::3 PM". I need help! Here is the code I'm using below.

```
@echo off
echo "AM, PM", or "24 Hour"?
echo[
choice /c 12 /m "1, or 2?"
if %errorlevel% equ 1 (
set timeformat=1
) else (
set timeformat=2
)
:setmrtime
if %timeformat% equ 1 (
set timerem=%time:~0,2%:%time:~3,2%
set hour=1
goto save
) else (
set hour=%time:~0,2%
set minute=%time:~3,2%
set pmam=AM
goto holdup
)
:holdup
if %hour% geq 12 (
set pmam=PM
) else (
set pmam=AM
)
if %hour% equ 12 (
set pmam=PM
)
if %hour% geq 13 (
set hour=%hour%-12
)
set timerem=%hour%:%minute% %pmam%
goto save
:save
cls
color 09
echo Save?
choice /c YN /m "Yes, or no? "
if %errorlevel%==1 (goto saving)
if %errorlevel%==2 (goto main)
:saving
set level=1
set health=10
set maxhealth=10
set money=0
set potions=0
set weapon=Hoe
set armor=Shirt
set bank=0
set fullrestores=0
set defence=0
set attack=1
set wlevel=1
set weaponlev=%wlevel%
set kills=0
set lastsave=%date% at %timerem%
set mystery=0
set timeformat=%timeformat%
set win=0
set /a save1=%save1%+1
attrib +h save.file
attrib -H save.file
(
echo %name%
echo %level%
echo %health%
echo %maxhealth%
echo %money%
echo %potions%
echo %weapon%
echo %armor%
echo %gender%
echo %bank%
echo %fullrestores%
echo %defence%
echo %attack%
echo %wlevel%
echo %weaponlev%
echo %kills%
echo %lastsave%
echo %mystery%
echo %timeformat%
echo %win%
)>save.file
attrib +H save.file
echo Saved.
pause
goto story
:story
cls
echo Story.
pause
:town
cls
echo Save?
choice /c YN /m "What? "
if %errorlevel%==2 (
exit
) else (
cls
echo %timerem%
goto save2
)
:save2
cls
color 0c
echo Save?
choice /c YN /m "Yes, or no? "
if %errorlevel%==1 (goto setdate)
if %errorlevel%==2 (goto town)
:saving2
attrib -H save.file
set timerem=%timerem%
set lastsave=%date% at %timerem%
(
echo %name%
echo %level%
echo %health%
echo %maxhealth%
echo %money%
echo %potions%
echo %weapon%
echo %armor%
echo %gender%
echo %bank%
echo %fullrestores%
echo %defence%
echo %attack%
echo %wlevel%
echo %weaponlev%
echo %kills%
echo %lastsave%
echo %mystery%
echo %timeformat%
echo %win%
)>save.file
attrib +H save.file
echo Saved.
pause
exit
```

Now don't worry, I pulled parts of my actual game and changed some lines to make it a mini-program.

For some odd reason, when I save my game twice, this code makes a "2::3 PM" or something similar, when it should be "3:24 PM", not "2::3 PM". This code is just not working. Is there anything I can possibly do to make this code work?

Comment: Please explain in a better way what you actually want to get. I see little sense in that batch file.

Comment: Subtract 12 from the hour. Also state your locale as English US/Aus use 12 hour clocks. So your code will be meaningless on most people's computers. Print out what `%time%` and `%date%` are in your country.

Comment: Hey Joshua, I don't see any obvious problems with your code, other than you ought to replace all your `if %hour% equ somethinglargerthan12` statements with `set /a hour %%= 12`.  I'm guessing it's a problem with code we don't see -- maybe with corrupt environment variables because you aren't using `setlocal`?  It might also help you troubleshoot delayed expansion problems if you indent your parenthetical code blocks, and comment out `@echo off` so you can see where things go awry during execution. Also consider scraping your timestamp from `wmic os get localdatetime` using a `for /f` loop.

Comment: Actually, to better explain, I need to add more code, although Noodles did give me a good suggestion to make the code simpler.

```

Comment: Do you know that format of `%time%` depends on which country the user running this batch file has configured in Windows region and language settings? It is not advisable to publish a batch file which depends on local settings of the user. I recommend the usage of a region independent solution for time usage.

Comment: Good idea, @Mofi! Thanks for the suggestion. :)

Comment: Here is a talking clock. https://pastebin.com/Jza4cywC